# Log Viewer - MDC Support

Tags: logging, log4j, viewer, mdc, ndc

I'm trying to find a log viewer for a log4j generated plain text file that supports MDC. I have looked at a few like Chainsaw, LogSaw, Otros but they seem to only support NDC.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

Try [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). It supports MDC (displayed as properties).

[image: OtrosLogViewer screenshot]

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 0):

Chainsaw supports it - try the latest developer snapshot: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Then use the configuration dialog to tell Chainsaw to process a regular text log file, and if you used a log4j.properties or log4j.xml with a FileAppender entry to generate the logfile, tell Chainsaw to use the FileAppender entry to build the configuration.